# Is it possible to compile c++ code with gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc

I know that you can add the c++ linker with `-lstdc++` and I do this, yet I am still getting an error.  `fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory`. Hence, gcc doesn't seem to know where to look for the headers.

What is the best way to proceed here, given that g++ is not an option?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why `g++` is not an option?

Comment: What is the extension of your files ? .c or .cpp ?

Comment: The file that is causing the error is a cpp, everything else is a c file.

Comment: I am using gcc/CMAKE to compile the code.

Comment: And yes I know that the problem is with the compiler.  I am just curious if there is a good way to make gcc aware of c++ headers such as iostream.

Comment: Aware of, yes, but anything that includes a C++ header is unlikely to compile in C, so save yourself the time and don't bother. Use the C++ compiler. [This sounds like an X-Y problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Can you expand on what you are really trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `gcc` treats a file with extension `.cpp` as C++ source:

```
$ cat test.cpp
#include <iostream>
int c;
$ gcc -c test.cpp
$
```

You can also explicitly specify the language with `-x language`:

```
$ mv test.cpp test.c
$ gcc -c -x c++ test.c
$
```

But why do you want to do this? You should have `g++` available and working. If not, that sounds like an incomplete or botched installation.